# Look up value in dictionary and put the value in cell - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table similar to this, to which I want to add a new "DESC" column:

| Header_1 | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row_1 |
| Second | row_2 |

On the other hand I have a table, called dictionary with the description:

| Code | DESC |
| --- | --- |
| row_1 | Description1 |
| row_2 | Description2 |

What formula can I use in Excel to get the value of the DESC row when the code matches?And let it stay like this:

| Header_1 | Another header | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row_1 | Description1 |
| Second | row_2 | Description2 |

Comment: `XLOOKUP`, `INDEX`/`MATCH`, `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `VLOOKUP`, make sure that your "Another header" ("Code") is unique.

Formula in `C6` (and dragged down) is `=VLOOKUP(B6,A2:B3,2,FALSE)`

Result:

[image]

More on [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)